# TextSwitcher "Slots Type" animation for number change

Tags: android, animation

I currently am using textswitcher and I am doing a slide in from left and slide out to right animation on a textview which contains a money amount.

I want to do an animation that when the number changes, it will sort of scroll to the number kind of like a slots machine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I would like to use android animations to do this if possible. Im sure I could just loop through, using a certain increment and change the textview along the way to the destination number but that just seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help, but it might be easier to do something with `Canvas` using the [drawText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) method, and then animating that drawable. Also, check the open source code for the clock [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock/) as they do similar animations